# Library wont connect? ERROR: THREE NOT DEFINED

Tags: three.js

I added the three.js library in the script section. I tried different ways from linking to the cdn website to downloading the three.js library and saving it in my directory but nothing works.When I try to create a scene, it does not recognize THREE and says not defined.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>practice</title>
 <style>
   body { margin: 0; }
   canvas { display: block; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <script src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
 <script src="js/three.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added pictures!

Comment: added the code, there you go!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the script of three.js before that of your main.js.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>practice</title>
    <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>
</head>

<body>


    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you didn't have scripts with `defer` or `async`, HTML parser will wait to download and execute the script and carry on.

Comment: Still not working. I had tried that before too, changing the order did nothing.

Comment: Ok, tried adding <script defer src=""> in the head and still did not work.

Comment: @Id1821 So maybe a problem with your downloaded js? It works fine on my computer without `<script src="js/three.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to mention this code to below to script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script>
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();  
</script>
```

According to the rule of javascript you have to define function or 
 variable definition first and after that you can use it.